# Como fazer Count Com Subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, pl-sql

Preciso Contar campos da mesa tabela, porém, esses campos tem diferentes tipos de filtros dentro do Where. Preciso que seja mostrada a informação consolidada, tentei fazer openquery mas retorna erro.

```
select ct.contratante,
       ct.fase,
       (select  count(distinct cpf) from #info_acionamentos xx with(nolock) where  ct.status_alo = 1) as alo,
       (select  count(distinct cpf) from #info_acionamentos xx with(nolock) where  ct.status_cpc = 1) as cpc
from #info_acionamentos ct
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Faz um union dos dois selects que voce comentou, é a forma mais simples de fazer

Comment: [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas - Postar código como imagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5485#5485)

Comment: Campos de mesa seriam as pernas da mesa, as cadeira? Você não colocou exemplo do que tem nas suas tabelas e do que você quer de resultado.

Comment: O que você quer fazer? Contar campos de tabela? Os campos tem filtros. Seria melhor apresentar melhor a sua questão

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se entendi direito o resultado que você pretente obter, a query poderia ser escrita da seguinte forma:

```
select ct.contratante,
       ct.fase,
       count(distinct CASE ct.status_alo WHEN 1 THEN ct.cpf ELSE NULL END) alo,
       count(distinct CASE ct.status_cpc WHEN 1 THEN ct.cpf ELSE NULL END) cpc
from #info_acionamentos ct
group by ct.contratante, ct.fase
```

Sem a necessidade de usar duas subqueries no select.

Comment: Muito obrigado, Excelente resposta 100% funcional. Enquanto uns tem capacidade de analisar e ajudar, outros só criticam o post.